# Как правильно обособить данный оборот с "в частности"?

Tags: пунктуация, вводные-слова

Планируется, что на этих объектах как раз и будут эксплуатироваться шаровые краны различного диаметра, и в частности, шаровой кран DN 300 мм PN 12,5 МПа для сред с высокой температурой.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Планируется, что на этих объектах как раз и будут эксплуатироваться шаровые краны различного диаметра, и в частности шаровой кран DN 300 мм PN 12,5 МПа для сред с высокой температурой.

Сочетание присоединительного союза "и" и вводного слова "в частности" относится к уточняющему обороту (со значением сужения).

Comment: Спасибо большое.